# Ubuntu 22 suddenly shuts down on 2 different machines, can Firefox be causing this?

Tags: firefox, 22.04

On my Lenovo Ideapad 3 and Lenovo Ideapad 3 Gaming 15ACH6 this occurs usually when I am browsing with Firefox.

Is this a known issue and what are some fixes?

The screen goes black and then it shuts down improperly like I hit and held the power button.

Edit: My Ubuntu 22.04 just hung and I did `cat /var/log/syslog` and see a bunch of stuff stopped.  I could move the mouse cursor but no mouse clicks nor keyboard. ctrl-alt-del and ctrl-alt-shift-"REISUB" did not work.

I skimmed `cat /var/log/syslog` and did not see anything that stood out.

Edit on Jan.6, 2023

It just shut down again so I checked the log below, can anyone see anything that stands out?  I also had a flash of green screen on a shutdown, not this time, but a few shutdowns ago.

https://gist.github.com/nyck33/f18fdf320529a460d35830f4f1fd8bd2

has lines like

```
an  6 14:39:11 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 update-notifier.desktop[4240]: Cannot stat file /proc/3906/fd/22: Permission denied
Jan  6 14:39:11 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 update-notifier.desktop[4240]: Cannot stat file /proc/3906/fd/23: Permission denied
Jan  6 14:39:11 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 update-notifier.desktop[4240]: Cannot stat file /proc/3906/fd/24: Permission denied
Jan  6 14:39:11 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 update-notifier.desktop[4240]: Cannot stat file /proc/3906/fd/25: Permission denied
Jan  6 14:39:11 nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 update-notifier.desktop[4240]: Cannot stat file /proc/3906/fd/26: Permission denied
```

Edit Jan.7, 2023
Green screen occurred: https://gist.github.com/nyck33/55712aaed8de118649eb96fa0768bede

Comment: you have provided absolutely no usefull information at all,please do!

Comment: @trondhansen I realize that and I just don't know why or how or what is occurring.  It goes to a black screen and then it shuts down.

Comment: Generally when a machine shuts itself down, there’s going to be a reason recorded in the logs. You can find this in the log application or, if you prefer the terminal, in `/var/log/syslog`. Without specifics, it will be darn near impossible to find a cause 

Comment: You haven't given enough information. I'm guessing that it shuts down due to low memory.

Comment: @matigo, what sort of output am I looking for in the log?  can I `grep` it?

Comment: @mLstudent33 you'll want to look for the lines written around the time of a reboot. So, if you can consistently make the system fail, check the time, then browse some sites with Firefox. After the system shuts down and you reboot, check the system log around the time of the failure and [edit] your question to include anything that might point to an error. I can't really suggest what to grep as we don't have any hints to go by at this point.

Comment: @matigo thanks, I'll keep that in mind next failure

Comment: @matigo I posted a gist if you have a moment to look at it.

Comment: I'm not seeing a definitive reason for the issue. However, the "your system is too slow" message tells me that Gnome is consuming a massive amount of resources in short bursts, slowing down the entire machine as a result. I wonder if the OOM manager is killing the browser due to resource constraints. The green flash would point to an issue with graphics resources/drivers 

Comment: @matigo I have dual boot, never have any issues with Windows 11 nor WSL2 but did install Nvidia drivers and Cuda on this Ubuntu 22 installation so that could be the cause I'm guessing.  My system seems to be operating normally right now.